want to insert TRUNK folder not initially created
I'm just getting totally wrapped around an axle on this. Help me unwind, please.
I created a project at, lets say, repo\projectA where my development files reside in/under projectA. (This is for Visual Studio, the .sln file is at projectA, while source code is in projectA\projectA)
Now of course I want to branch; and since I didn't start off with a structure like repo\projectA\trunk\projectA{dev files} I'm finding it awkward.
In the repo browser (I'm using TortoiseSVN BTW), I just created a TRUNK folder under ProjectA, then dragged the contents down under TRUNK. But then on my dev machine I couldn't make commits.
I thought the tortoise context menu "relocate" (on the dev machine/folder) would be the answer, but that seems not to work. That seems to want to move from repoX to repoY, and not repoX/ProjA --> repoX/ProjA/foo or even repoX/ProjB.
Can someone walk me through the "correct" way to move my stuff down under TRUNK?
